# Mouseover on tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter, button, mouseover

Is it possible to get the popup option (pop function in the code) on hovering the cursor on the button?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, BOTH, Menu

def pop(bt):
    try:
        x = bt.winfo_rootx()+238
        y = bt.winfo_rooty()+10
        popup.tk_popup(x, y, 0)
    finally:
        popup.grab_release()


root = tk.Tk()

popup = Menu(root, tearoff=0,relief='raised')
popup.add_command(label="About")
popup.add_command(label="User manual")
popup.add_command(label="Contact us")

button1 =tk.Button(root, text="HELP",height=3,width=26,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HelpPage))                   
button1.configure(command = lambda: pop(button1))
button1.place(x=0,y=0
              )
root.mainloop()
```

.

```
button1.bind('<Enter>',pop(button1)) #gives the following output without the mouse cursor over that button.
```

[image]

Comment: You can use bind sequences `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` to *post* and *unpost* the menu resp.

Comment: @Saad, I have tried this method before but getting the above result( please find the screenshot )

Comment: By default, an argument is passed to the callback function in an event. So it should be `button1.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: pop(button1))`. Also, *please note `<Enter>` is not the same as `<enter>`*, it should start with capital "E".

Comment: @Saad, Thanks its working. Do you know how to hide the popup when the cursor is not on the button? i know this is not in the question but i couldn't find it so please help me if you know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = None

def leave_window(event):
    global window
    if 0 < root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx() < button.winfo_width():
        if 0 < root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty() < button.winfo_height():
            # Mouse still over button
            return None
    if window is not None:
        window.destroy()
        window = None

def create_window(event):
    global window
    if window is not None:
        # The window is already open
        return None
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.overrideredirect(True)
    label = tk.Label(window, text="Text", bg="black", fg="white")
    label.pack()
    window.update()
    # Move the window to the cursor's
    x = root.winfo_pointerx()
    y = root.winfo_pointery()-window.winfo_height()
    window.geometry("+%i+%i" % (x, y))
    window.bind("<Leave>", leave_window)


root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text="-------- Hover the mouse here --------")
button.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
button.bind("<Enter>", create_window)
button.bind("<Leave>", leave_window)

root.mainloop()
```

I binded to `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` to check if the mouse is over the button. If it is, it creates a window with a label called text. You can change it to it showing the menu.

For more answers look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20399243/11106801).

Answer (score 0):

Please bind your Button with mouse enter and call pop function.
Check out this code :

```
button1.bind('<Enter>', pop)
```

Control your popup location as well as destroy popup on '' case again bind it and call custom function that will destroy popup.

Comment: I have tried this method before but the result is different. please find the attached screenshot. @ExplooreX

Comment: Your answer will give an error because in the function `pop` the parameter `bt` doesn't have `winfo_rooty()` functions.

Comment: @Saad thanks for that point : `button1.bind('<Enter>', pop)` change your code to `button1.bind('<Enter>',lambda eff: pop(button1)) `

Comment: `x = bt.winfo_rootx()+238`    `y = bt.winfo_rooty()+10`    `popup.tk_popup(x, y, 0)`  also add these line of code which I didn't considered

Answer (score 0):

You need `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` bind sequences to map and unmap the Menu. Tkinter `Menu` has two methods `post` and `unpost` where `post` shows the menu at given coordinates, and `unpost` hides it away. Unfortunately, I couldn't test it as the unpost functionality doesn't work on macOS or Linux *[[refer to this link for the same]](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2002-September/161459.html)*. I also changed the `x`, `y` coords to map the Menu in the center of the widget *(Button)*, it can be changed if required.

---

*Here is the complete sample code.*

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, BOTH, Menu


def pop(evt):
    but = evt.widget
    if str(evt.type) == "Enter":
        # Map the menu in the center of the width.
        x = but.winfo_rootx() + int(but.winfo_width()/2)
        y = but.winfo_rooty() + int(but.winfo_height()/2)
        popup.tk_popup(x, y)

    elif str(evt.type) == "Leave":
        popup.unpost()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

popup = Menu(root, tearoff=0, relief='raised')
popup.add_command(label="About")
popup.add_command(label="User manual")
popup.add_command(label="Contact us")

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="HELP", height=3, width=26)
button1.bind('<Enter>', pop)
button1.bind('<Leave>', pop)
button1.pack(pady=100)

root.mainloop()
```

*Like said, `unpost` doesn't work on macOS or Linux, so I couldn't test the sample code 100% but it should work fine.*

Comment: Thank you <Enter> is working fine but <Leave> is not working in the windows. @Saad