# Is there a possible way to detect label's text under moving cursor in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, tooltip

I try to find a simple way to solve my problem written in title. I use python with tkinter and my goal is popup a tooltip-like widget on a map where it contains different cities. That means since every cities have different names and data and that "tooltip" should show relevant infos I had to figure out how to change "tooltip" label's text regaring hovered city. Googled it before anyway. All in all I need a dinamically generated tooltip not one with fixed text. Here's a picture how it should look.
[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLnw9.jpg)

I have a lame solution where all cities' names have two x,y position and I could set a bunch of if conditionals finding out whether cursor's position is among them, but there must be something, a smarter way I don't know yet.

How can I detect hovered label's text, name, etc. easily is my question. I thought somebody can help me out with this. Every feedback is welcome. Thx.

PS: English is not my native language sorry if it's a little confusing I hope the gist will go over.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66505323/11106801). It is basically what you need (just change the button to a label).

Comment: Create a tooltip or use one from `Pmw` and bind it to the label you want.

Comment: Thank you guys. These ideas are promising but not yet satisfying. Anyone else?