# How to create a tooltip for radio buttons in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, tooltip

I want to know if it is possible to add tooltip functionality to the radio buttons in tkinter. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221956/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-make-tooltips-in-tkinter) is for normal buttons and being an inexperienced programmer I am unable to adapt it to my code. Can anyone please help?

```html
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter

root = Tk()

root.wm_title("Welcome")



background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


############################################## Solar Panel selection ###################################################
v = IntVar()
v.set(1)  # initializing the choice (type 1)

Panels = [
    ("SPR-445NJ-WHT-D", 1),
    ("SPR-425E-WHT-D", 2),
    ("X21-345", 3),
    ("SPR-327NE-WHT-D", 4),
    ("T5-SPR-318E", 5)
]

def ShowChoice():
    ch = v.get()
    print ch

Label(root,
      text=""" Select the Solar Panel""",
      justify=LEFT, fg="white", bg='#660033',
      font="Helvetica 10 bold",
      padx=20).pack(fill=X,pady=10)

for txt, val in Panels:
    Radiobutton(root,
                text=txt,
                indicatoron=0,
                fg="darkgreen",
                font="Helvetica 10 bold",
                width=10,
                padx=20,
                variable=v,
                command=ShowChoice,
                value=val).pack()

root.minsize(width=400, height=666)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have yo not tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/36221216/6622817 from your link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest way to make tooltips in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221956/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-make-tooltips-in-tkinter)