# is there any way to create a window when text is highlighted in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, window, highlight, ttk

[click to view picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjglF.png)

is there any way to create this, this is a picture when link in Wikipedia is highlighted

Comment: you could add a pop window

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I display tooltips in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221956/how-do-i-display-tooltips-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

by running the following function you can see how a pop window will look like Tkinter program

```
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
NORM_FONT = ("Helvetica", 10)
SMALL_FONT = ("Helvetica", 8)

def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("!")
    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=NORM_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
    popup.mainloop()
```

later you could use it in your program by removing somelines.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a new instance of `Tk`, and you shouldn't be calling `mainloop` a second time. That's not how tkinter is designed to be used. This promotes a bad programming practice.

Comment: @Bryan I know that, and I wrote that code so that he can run individually this code and see how it works.‍♀️

Comment: I need a window which popups when a text is highlighted and automatically destroys when the highlight is removed. this window contains the default three buttons of window and appears only when the command is run, how to run this function when the label in another window is highlighted ?