# Customize Message and Dialogue Box in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing an application in which I have to guide user how to perform a certain task. To do that I have to draw rectangle and show a box around widgets. Like this [image]

Till now I am able to develop tkinter transparent and topmost windows which is displaying the rectangle, here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
w = Canvas(root , bg = "white", bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
w.create_rectangle(30, 30, 100, 100)
root.lift()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
root.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
w.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

But how can I display that box with text in it, I have tried using dialogue box and message box but how can I customize them like this?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221956/how-do-i-display-tooltips-in-tkinter

Comment: yes Thankyou this is what I was looking for