# How to use tix balloon on a function event?

Tags: python, tkinter, balloon-tip, tix

I have a program that will count the index length of a highlighted area. I wanted to use tix balloon to show the the result. But in order to use the tix balloon, it required me bind it to the a widget. Instead of binding it to a whole widget, I only want the balloon to show once when a certain event is being called.

**Demo of my program (Count start and end index of the highlighted area)**
[image]

**Expected output**
The balloon will show the result beside the highlighted area
[image]

**Code**

```
root.mainloop()from tkinter import *

import tkinter.tix as tkx

def print_count(event):
    if text.tag_ranges('sel'):
        global s0 , s1
        s0 = text.index("sel.first")
        s1 = text.index("sel.last")
        countstringstart = s0.split('.')[1]
        countstringend = s1.split('.')[1]
        print(countstringstart)
        print(countstringend)
        waitshowballon()

root = tkx.Tk()
global text
text = Text(root)
text.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', print_count)
text.pack()

def waitshowballon():
    tooltip = tkx.Balloon(root, initwait=100)
    tooltip.bind_widget(text, balloonmsg=s0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I dont think `tix` is still usable. Try `Pmw` or make your own.

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes tix is still working, i had edit the sample code above. But the balloon doesn't follow the cursor, it only show at the center. [Image](https://ibb.co/8bnKJSq)

Comment: Does it have any option to follow the cursor? You might need to make your own tooltip so that it will be above your cursor always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own tooltip. tix don't seem to provide position parameter.

Creating your own tooltip is quite simpler than you think. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36221216/12198502) answer will give you an idea on how to make your own tooltip.

Create a `show` function that takes the indexes as parameters. Use `.bbox(index)` to get the position of the index and display the tooltip just above the selected letter.

Sample code:

```py
from tkinter import *

class TextToolTip:

    def __init__(self, root, widget:Text, delay=0):
        
        self.parent = root
        self.delay = delay
        self.widget = widget
        
        self.top = None
        self.pos_x, self.pos_y = 0, 0

        self.i0, self.i1 = "", ""
        self.after_id = None

        self.msg=''
        
        self.bind()
        
    def bind(self):
        self.parent.bind('<Button>', self.hide)
        self.parent.bind('<Configure>', self.move)
        self.widget.tag_bind('sel', '<Enter>', self._display) #  remove this if hover tooltip is not necessary
        self.widget.tag_bind('sel', '<Leave>', self.tempHide)
                

    def tempHide(self, event):
        # similar to hide method the only difference is that this does't reset self.i0 and self.i1
        if self.top:
            self.top.destroy()
            self.top = None

    
    def hide(self, event=None):
        # destroys the top level
        if self.top:
            self.top.destroy()
            self.top = None
      
        self.i0, self.i1 = "", ""

    def move(self, event):
        # moves the tooltip along with the window
        if self.top:
            x, y = self.calcPos()
            if x and y:
                self.top.wm_geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")
                
            else:
                self.hide()

    def _display(self, event=None):
        # creates the tool tip
        if self.top is None:
            self.top = Toplevel(self.parent)
            self.top.wm_overrideredirect(True)
            
            label = Label(self.top, text=self.msg, justify='left',
                           background="black", foreground='white',
                          relief='solid', borderwidth=1)

            label.pack()
            
            x, y = self.calcPos()
            if x and y:
                self.top.wm_geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")
                    
            else:
                self.hide()
                return         

    def calcPos(self):  # calculates the position to display the tool tip
        
        try:
            self.widget.update_idletasks()
            b1, b2 = self.widget.bbox(self.i0), self.widget.bbox(self.i1)
            win_x, win_y = self.parent.winfo_x(), self.parent.winfo_y()
            return win_x + ((b2[0]+b1[0])//2), win_y + b1[1]

        except Exception:

            return None, None
            
    def show(self, msg, i0, i1):  
        """ pass in the index and the message (note: must pass a valid index ctrl+a might not provide
                correct index. A simple conditionl stmt to check should do the job.)"""
        if self.top:
            self.hide()

        if self.after_id:
            self.parent.after_cancel(self.after_id)
            self.after_id = None
        
        self.i0, self.i1 = i0, i1
        self.msg = msg
        self.after_id = self.parent.after(self.delay, self._display)
        
        
def print_count(event):
    if text.tag_ranges('sel'):
        global s0 , s1
        s0 = text.index("sel.first")
        s1 = text.index("sel.last")
        countstringstart = s0.split('.')[1]
        countstringend = s1.split('.')[1]

        waitshowballon(countstringstart, countstringend)

    else:
        tooltip.hide()    

    
root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.bind('<<Selection>>', print_count)
text.pack()

tooltip = TextToolTip(root, text, 500)  # pass in the rot, text widget and delay


def waitshowballon(cs, ce):
 
    tooltip.show(f"{cs}-{ce}", s0, s1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, thanks again. It seem like a great idea to create my own toolkit instead of using a ready made preset