# I'm using tix Balloon and I want to make a hovering text which will change according to some variable

Tags: python, tkinter, balloon, tix

The problem is that when I change the message, the old message still appears and the new one is just shown above it. is there any way to fix it?

Comment: the tix lib is deprecated. You could try idlelib or create your own tooltip.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I display tooltips in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221956/how-do-i-display-tooltips-in-tkinter)

Comment: @Thingamabobs My problem is that I want the tooltip to change depending on some variable but when I do that, instead of changing the messages are appearing on top of each other.